# Create Draft mail in Office 365 via Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, office365, bearer-token, outlook-restapi

I have a Web API backend with EF and use AzureAD to authenticate my (office365)users of the web application that is written in AngularJS.

Now I want to create a draft mail in my Web API but I don't know where to start.

Can I just call the Office 365 mail API in my Web API?
POST https://outlook.office365.com/api/{version}/me/sendmail

But how do I pass the authentication token with it?

Here is the Auth config that I use now and it works for other data requests.

```
public static class Auth
{
    internal static void ConfigureCors(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // TODO: Configure to only allow ESS Web UI
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }

    internal static void ConfigureAuth(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = Settings.Default.Audience
                },
                Tenant = Settings.Default.Tenant
            });
    }
}
```

Any one how has some sample code to make the correct request to the Office 365 API? Thank you! I'm new to the Office 365 API and this website:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

is not so clear for me to know how to handle this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating the proper REST request yourself (using `HttpClient` or something similar), or you can use the .NET SDK for the Office 365 APIs. There's a [getting started tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) that shows how to use the SDK. It retrieves mail rather than creates, but it should get you started. Creating a draft (with the SDK) is covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#CreateDraftClient).

For authentication you need to get an OAuth2 token, which gets passed in the `Authorization` header as a bearer token. The Azure Active Directory Authentication Library can be used for this.

If you choose to implement the REST yourself, the format of the request is covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#CreateNewDraft). There's an overview of getting started with raw REST [here](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted).