# Create a draft email in Outlook 365 and then open it for editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, office365, office365api

We're planning to create draft Outlook 365 emails from our ASP.NET MVC C# code which is running as an Azure App. That looks relatively straightforward in the [Outlook Mail REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) and there's some useful info on that in [this reply too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295313/1879019).

What I'd then like to do is open that message in Outlook 365 in a new browser tab so the user can edit it before pushing send, but I can't seem to find a way to do that?

So, the process I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Create draft message in O365 Outlook using the Rest API
2. Save that draft
3. Open a new browser tab displaying that saved draft message in Outlook 365

Step 3 is what I can't find a way to do, is it possible?

If I open an email in Outlook 365 the URL is generic and doesn't contain a unique ID for the message object, so I'm not sure if there's any way to get a URL that links directly to an email message?

Comment: you can probably add subject to email and then retrieve it using that

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if they're using on prem Outlook you could create a hyperlink using mailto:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

I have subsequently found this which should meet your criteria:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477920/4528266

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloshm/2016/01/16/how-to-compose-a-new-message-or-event-and-populate-fields-in-office365/#comment-1645

Comment: That's definitely a good start.  I guess there are a couple of potential issues with it: adding email attachments and also that the message isn't secure as it's forming part of the URL, which could be an issue in light of GDPR

Answer (score 2):

If you need to keep the mail item after it is shown to a user you need to provide the UI in your application and use [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) for sending it. So, you will be able to refer to the item later.

As a possible workaround you may consider automating the desktop edition of Outlook installed on the machine. See [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Astafiev - sorry, my question wasn't very clear originally, this is all ASP code so I don't have access to the local copy of Outlook (and indeed there may not be one for some of our clients if they are working from public computers)

Comment: Then you need to provide a custom UI for composing emails on your pages. \